# Why do two identical spans have different widths?

Tags: html, css

I have two identical spans but for some reason the second one is displayed narrower. JSFiddle is down right now so here is a complete html example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="background-color:#ccc; margin-right:0.125em;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
        <span style="background-color:#ccc; margin-right:0.125em;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems the last one is always narrower but if I add more spans it gets even weirder. The first one will sometimes have a different width, with a value in between the wide middle ones and the narrow last one.

What am I missing?

Comment: @SridharR: `JSFiddle is down right now` and I can confirm that.

Comment: use [codepen](http://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first on an extra space is inserted. If all spans are one-liners it works as expected:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="background-color:#ccc; margin-right:0.125em;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="background-color:#ccc; margin-right:0.125em;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="background-color:#ccc; margin-right:0.125em;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

What are you trying to archive? If you want all spans to have the same length you should do that in CSS by setting

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. It's a poor man's bar chart that's generated dynamically by the application. I didn't know about ``inline-block``.

Comment: For future reference, I've just figured out the last piece of the puzzle: since the width is defined in ``em``s, the computed value comes out as ``10.5px`` so Chrome alternates between 10px and 11px (to minimize rounding errors?). Setting a width in px fixes that.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to prefer specifying a font and define everything in rem as they give a bigger grid which (I think) makes it easier to align stuff. However that's just a personal preference, px is equally fine.

Comment: I'm so behind the times, I thought ``rem`` was a typo. Good to know though. Everything else on this site is in ``em``s so I'm sticking to that but it's good to know why the widths vary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason, that margin does not extends the width of parent element
http://jsbin.com/eHaNIR/1

Answer (score 0):

Problem is space between tags.

Doesnt work:

```
<body>
  <span margin-right:0.125em;"> &bnsp; </span>
  <span margin-right:0.125em;"> &bnsp; </span>
</body>
```

Works well:

```
<body>
  <span margin-right:0.125em;"> &bnsp; </span>
  <span margin-right:0.125em;"> &bnsp; </span>
  works well because of this text
</body>
```

How to hack it:

```
span:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block
}
```

How to fix it correctlly (minify code):

```
<body><span margin-right:0.125em;"> &bnsp; </span><span margin-right:0.125em;"> &bnsp; </span></body>
```

**Demo of fix with additional text:**
http://jsbin.com/AFuPomI/1/edit

**this can also help:**
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/